# How do I setup a Sqlite3 Model Class Generation class for use in Unity 5+ Using C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, database-design, unity-game-engine

### TLDR Short and Sweet

**I want to generate Sqlite Database Model Classes Programmatically or Infer them using C# for the use of a Database system in Unity.**

### Overview & Full Explanation

So First off I would like to start this question with what I am trying to do. I decided to take a base Sqlite library that I used as a base to handle the Sqlite interactions. I am writing a full wrapper class to handle these interactions more cleanly and effectively. The goal is to incorporate this model generation system into that wrapper. Currently I am working with Unity 5.3. I am trying to write a Database System for an RPG game that my company and I are developing. While designing and developing this database system we made the decision to use Sqlite and handling our items/actors/enemies....

The issue is not really necessarily the ability to convert all these base classes to model classes and have proper converting methods to handle converting to and from database fields. This question is more about how to handle in Unity using C# to generate model classes directly either with a class wrapper to convert the classes to database supported model classes programmatically and efficiently.

### Example of the Goal / Current Problem (PSEUDOCODE)

**What I currently have to do right now.**

```
//Example of what I have to to right now.

public class Weapon
{
    public string m_name;
    public int m_attack_damage;
    // ETC...
}


//This is an example class that will contain game logic handling Actor
//currently.. Because I have a type that is not regonized by the Sqlite Database
//it will not create a table/field for this class as a type due to this without a ModelClass wrapper to convert those values.
public class Actor
{
    public string m_Name { get; set; } //This translates perfectly to the SQLite database.
    public int m_Age { get; set; }     //This translates perfectly to the SQLite database.

    //THIS WILL NOT TRANSLATE TO THE SQLite DB without a Model Wrapper.
    public Weapon m_Weapon { get; set; } //This is a type of a custom class called Weapon. 

    //This is the model class I need to pass to the Table/Field to be translated correctly.
    public ActorDBModel ToDBModel()
    {
        var model = new ActorDBModel();

        model.Name = m_Name;
        model.Age = m_Age;
        model.Weapon_Name = m_Weapon.m_Name;
        model.Weapon_Attack_Damage = m_Weapon.m_attack_damage;
        return model
    }

    //ETC...
}

//THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TO CREATE IN ORDER TO HANDLE THE ABOVE CLASS

public class ActorDBModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public string Weapon_Name {get; set;} //These are set from the Actor
    public int Weapon_Attack_Damage {get; set;} // These are set from the ActorDBModel

    //ETC...
}
```

**Goal**

```
//This is an example class that will contain game logic handling Actor
//The goal is to be able to convert class types and other types into Sqlte regonized values with Attributes if possible.
public class Actor
{
    public string m_Name { get; set; } //This translates perfectly to the SQLite database.
    public int m_Age { get; set; }     //This translates perfectly to the SQLite database.
    [SQLConvertToFields] //or something of this nature or have it inferred completely by my wrapper.
    public Weapon m_Weapon { get; set; } //This is a type of a custom class called Weapon. 

    //NO NEED FOR A MODEL CLASS!!

    //ETC...
}
```

### Background

I Love to write clean, simple, and effective code. I have been stumped on this issue for quite a while now, Thus the reason I created a stackoverflow account to post my question for this. From someone who loves coding and has been coding since 2004, stackoverflow has helped me so much just by researching other peoples questions and answers. So thank you all! I Hope someone can help me overcome this roadblock so that I can proceed with my system =)

Upon request I will post Code Snippets and such with any questions or implementations as soon as I get any messages or responses requiring that.

**CODE ENVIRONMENT**

- Unity 5.3.2
- C# 4 (Unity subset)
- The SQLite library that I used is SQLite4Unity3d - https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d

(Also Note: I apologize if my question and information is too long or needs to clarified I will be more than happy to accommodate if and when needed. This is my first question ever posted on stackoverflow of my 12 years of coding experience.. So I may handle it oddly. SORRY! )

Comment: hi @JeffreyMiller I too sometimes write overlong questions  :)  I can't believe someone downvoted your first question.  You seem to be asking *"how to handle in Unity using C# to generate model classes directly either with a class wrapper to convert the classes to database supported model classes programmatically and efficiently."*  I actually have no clue what that means. Could you put in three lines of code showing what milieu we are in here.

Comment: Here is an utterly unrelated general comment (expect that in Comments!) If you're making an "rpg" surely the whole concept is multiplayer right. You will in a word have to use firebase (bye, Parse!  :) ) so to some extent I'm puzzled as to what possible help a local "database" (fortunately I'm old enough to know the word :) ) would be ...

Comment: @JoeBlow Thank you for your response and sure! I can try. Right now at this stage I'm so stumped on the concept it's been hard to really conceptualize the code however I will go ahead and write some code as an example on how I would like it to be used and the goal.

Comment: @JoeBlow I added the snippets as you requested I hope this helps understand my question and goal more!

Also! On the side general comment note: This is an offline Coach Co-op RPG with the future possibility of becoming more hopefully. Also do you have any suggestions about anything else that could be related to storing and handling data properly in unity?

Comment: btw someone downvoted your question - I voted it up!  :)  I see it's offline. Sure it's great to use sql.  I'm just wrapping my head around the question.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it! ^

Comment: I don't really understand your question completely, but are you talking about Custom Attributes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx

Comment: @Savlon not quite. I know how to impliment custom attributes. What I'm trying to sort out is how to gather all the fields and structures in a class with a type of reflection or something to get the types of fields in a class and append the class name to it when it is tagged with a custom attribute in my example. I am trying to find a simplified way to remove the need for a model class and just use the main logic driven data structures. Thank you for the link though I have throughly researched attributes over the course of my C# Development experience =)

Comment: Oh I see... If your code works and you think it's a messy way of doing it, you should head over to CodeReview.SE and post this there. They may know a different way of achieving the same result.

Comment: @Savlon Thanks for the advice! I will post it in there I am going to keep this up here and see if anyone else has ideas or something that can assist with this. I am still learning the ropes and such for stackoverflow I may be a bit noobish on here I lurked here for so many years and I usually ask my other work colleagues but even they are stumped on how to handle this one. I really do appreciate your feedback though!

Comment: Ok nice one! Good luck Jeffery!